# Meaning of "Klatsche"

Tags: meaning-in-context

A headline on Bild Sport read:

> Böse Klatsche für die Wölfe! Bei Everton gibt's in der Europa League eine herbe 1:4-Klatsche.

What does "Klatsche" mean in this context? According to the dictionary, the main meanings are "gossip", "sneak", and "fly swatter", but none seems to fit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Klatsche" is an informal word for defeat or loss. It is mostly used in sports context and to express the inferiority of the said team.

Additionally, *böse* and *herbe* are used to emphasize the defeat, and not used in their original meaning (*evil* / *sour*). Either of those in combination with *Klatsche* would be translated with something like *brutal defeat*

Comment: As you already mentioned some collocations, I'd just like to add another one: "eine Klatsche kassieren"

Comment: We do use "spanked" often in English when talking about a loss in sports. Sounds similar usage to me.

Answer (score 8):

Klatsche normally means slap, usually in the face. Fliegenklatsche is fly swatter.

Klatsche is also used as a bitter defeat, humiliating like a slap in the face.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, the word is often used in sports and politics: when one team really loses badly, the losing team has received a "Klatsche" – or the wining team gave the losing team a "Klatsche".

But the word has also a broader meaning - and I suppose this is the origin of the above usage: ironically "***klatschen***" is actually the german word for *clapping*. But the meaning of this *clapping* is not only *applauding* – but also something like *slapping*. For example you kill flies with a "***Fliegenklatsche***" or short "***Klatsche***" - a "*fly slapper*" / "*fly swatter*".

And then there is the very bad street slang – if you're planning to beat somebody XY up you could ask your gang friend to joins in: "*Lass uns XY klatschen*" (="*Let's clap XY*) which basicalley means "*let's beat XY up*".

Not that bad is yet annother meaning, which is close to "a slap in the face" –– so if somebody asks you "***Soll ich Dir eine klatschen?***" you better say no – because literally it would mean "*shall I clap you one?*" which stands for "*would you like to get a slap in the face?*".

For "*gossip*" a shorter version is used: "***Klatsch***" – and it is actually male "***der Klatsch***" – but the term you're asking about is female "***die Klatsche***" – but I guess they are still somehow related. When people meet for coffee and gossipping they also sometimes call it "***Kaffeeklatsch***".

So I suppose the sports and politics related meaning of "Klatsche" comes from somewhere between all those meanings mentioned above – and I personally would describe it as *a team feeling* of getting ***a slap in the team face***.

See also http://www.dict.cc/?s=slapping